# Cannot resolve symbol R in android studio and could not find com.android.build:aapt2:3.3.0-alpha05-4916870 error in android studrio

Tags: java, android, maven, android-studio

Image :

[image]

getting this error after I update my gradle version

Could not find com.android.tools.build:aapt2:3.3.0-alpha05-4916870.

Searched in the following locations:
  - file:/C:/Users/xervice111/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.3.0-alpha05-4916870/aapt2-3.3.0-alpha05-4916870.pom
  -

file:/C:/Users/xervice111/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.3.0-alpha05-4916870/aapt2-3.3.0-alpha05-4916870-windows.jar
  - 
file:/C:/Users/xervice111/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.3.0-alpha05-4916870/aapt2-3.3.0-alpha05-4916870.pom
  - 
file:/C:/Users/xervice111/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.3.0-alpha05-4916870/aapt2-3.3.0-alpha05-4916870-windows.jar
  - 
file:/C:/Users/xervice111/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.3.0-alpha05-4916870/aapt2-3.3.0-alpha05-4916870.pom
  - file:/C:/Users/xervice111/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.3.0-alpha05-4916870/aapt2-3.3.0-alpha05-4916870-windows.jar
  -

https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.3.0-alpha05-4916870/aapt2-3.3.0-alpha05-4916870.pom
  -

https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.3.0-alpha05-4916870/aapt2-3.3.0-alpha05-4916870-windows.jar
Required by:
    project :app

Answer (score 0):

Aapt2 error occurs when u have error in any .xml file. Check all the .xml file, this may solve ur issue.

Answer (score 0):

Just `Invalidate caches / Restart` under `File`